# jQuery Mobile vclick in ios fires twice in different pages

Tags: android, ios, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm developing an app with jquery mobile and cordova and it all works great except in ios devices where the vlcick event is fired twice, but in different pages, i mean, i fire a vclick to change the page, and another vclick is automatically fired in the button that would be in the same position in the page that i'm changing to.

Somthing similar is happening when i touch the physical back button on my android, it shows me the previous page but instantlly returns to the page whre i touched the back button.

Answer (score 1):

You should stop the propagation:

```
$(".you_selector").on("tap", function () {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    // Your logic
});
```

Comment: it worked perfect for ios. Now, can you help me with the same problem pressing back button in android devices with physical buttons?